# Can an :after background-image be used to overlap the next element?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have an image that I'd like to add as an :after element to a nav bar. The point being that the :after would cover the top portion of the next section (this is part of the design).

The :after is set as position: absolute with a top: 100% and it seems to disappear under the next element and z-index hasn't helped. When the top is set to anything less than 100%, you can see the :after element above the nav.

The markup:

```
<nav>Contents</nav>
<div>Contents</div>
```

The CSS:

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

nav:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 66px;
    background-image: url('image.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
}

No CSS for div yet...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect that all you need is to set the `z-index` on the Content div to lower than that of the pseudo-element **but** note that the Content div must have a position setting on anything other than `static`...`position:relative` is usually sufficient.

Comment: It will cover. do you have overflow:hidden on the nav and the parent of nav?

Comment: Your code seems like it should work as-is: https://jsfiddle.net/8w7kz5Lc/ If you can provide a JS Fiddle where it is not working I can try to fix it.

Comment: try setting the parent container (the one above nav element) to position relative as well. The psuedo element might not be inheriting the parent's relative style since it's appended afterwards, not within.

Comment: thanks @Paulie_D but that didn't do it.

Comment: See my answer. Just set the z-index of the pseudo-element to higher than 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to set the z-index on the Content div to lower than that of the pseudo-element but note that the Content div must have a position setting on anything other than static...position:relative is usually sufficient.

Alternatively, just set the `z-index` of the pseudo-element to higher than that of the div (which will probably default to 1).

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
nav:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 66px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
div {
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<nav>Nav</nav>
<div>Contents</div>
```